# webget in Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there any command equivalent to `webget` in WindOS's PowerShell?

I am trying to create a script to download all publicly available files from the website. I am making the custom script because I need to store the files in specific directory structure (depending on name, type and size).

Comment: Some light searching provided several options for what webget might be considered in this context: a bash function or one of several different executables. Could you be more specific regarding what behavior you are looking for like a full web spider solution or just download all resources of a specific type (e.g. images or videos) from a page?

Comment: @Goyuix, sure. I need to download heterogeneous files/assets (such as images, videos). I have a list for remote files location and their directory structures, which are accessible via HTTP. I need to fetch them and store them locally in a specific order, while applying custom filters. For example, images with xxx prefix in the filename should go to specific directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell v2, use a WebClient:

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $localFileName)
```

In v3, the `Invoke-WebResquest` cmdlet:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $localFileName
```

Another option is with the `Start-BitsTransfer` cmdlet:

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $source -Destination $destination
```

Comment: I am using PS v3 in Windows 7 ([Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)), and Invoke-WebRequest is returning handsome amount of information. One question; what is the *typeof* `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri` cmdlet in your example?

Comment: Pipe the result to the get-member cmdlet, it will tell you the type name and all of its members.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell V3, you can use the new cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` to send an http or https request to a web site/service e.g.:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -URI http://www.bing.com?q=how+many+feet+in+a+mile
```

However to specifically download a file it is probably easiest to use the .NET API WebClient.DownloadFile() e.g.:

```
$remoteUri = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png"
$fileName = "$pwd\logo.png"
$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
$webClient.DownloadFile($remoteUri, $fileName)
```

Comment: +1 I am using PS v3 in Windows 7 ([Windows6.1-KB2506143-x64.msu](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)), and Invoke-WebRequest is returning handsome amount of information. One question; what is the *typeof* $r in your example?

Comment: It is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject`.  You can see this by piping $r through Get-Member e.g. `$r | Get-Member`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the .NET class `WebClient` to download files.

```
PS > $source = "http://www.unsite.fr/untruc.zip"
PS > $destination = "c:\temp\untruc.zip" 
PS >
PS >$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
PS >$wc.DownloadFile($source, $destination)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works great! .NET objects certainly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a "native" PowerShell cmdlet that works in PowerShell V2 or V3, I recommend `Get-HttpResource` from the PowerShell Community Extensions ([PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com/)). While PSCX surprisingly does not have the API available online (you have to install the extensions then you can use the normal PowerShell help to explore each command), I managed to find the API for Get-HttpResource [here](http://www.powershellmanual.com/get-httpresource). Using the cmdlet can be as simple as this:

```
 $myPage = Get-HttpResource http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell
```

However, there are a variety of parameters to the cmdlet that let you specify media type, credentials, encoding, proxy, user agent, and more.